# choose random value from enum

Tags: swift, enums

I have an `UIColor extension` with `enum` named `myColors`:

```
enum myColors {
    static let backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: "#373737")
    static let strokeColor = UIColor(hex: "#FFFCF9")
    static let red = UIColor(hex: "#FF6978")
    static let green  = UIColor(hex: "#BCE784")
    static let blue   = UIColor(hex: "#B1DDF1")
    static let yellow = UIColor(hex: "#FFFD98")
    static let purple = UIColor(hex: "#A09ABC")
}
```

I'm trying to set a `sprite` color to be one of these colors randomly (red, green, blue, yellow, purple).
I found few answers here on Stack Overflow but none worked.
I tried to do it like this:

```
let sprite = Player(x,y,color: myColors(rawValue: myColors.purple.rawValue+1)
```

But it didn't work.
Purple is the last item on the enum so I chose it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest avoiding storing the object `UIColor` inside an `enum`, my approach:

```
 enum myColors: String {
    case backgroundColor = "#373737"
    case strokeColor = "#FFFCF9"
    case red = "#FF6978"
    case green  = "#BCE784"
    case blue   = "#B1DDF1"
    case yellow = "#FFFD98"
    case purple = "#A09ABC"


    static func randomColor() -> UIColor {
        let colorsToGetRandomly = [myColors.red, myColors.green, myColors.blue, myColors.yellow, myColors.purple]
        let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(colorsToGetRandomly.count)))
        let color = colorsToGetRandomly[index].rawValue
        return UIColor(hex: color)
    }
}

myColors.randomColor()
```

Answer (score 4):

Following on from @vadian's answer, to return a random colour…

```
enum MyColors : String {
    case background = "#373737"
    case stroke = "#FFFCF9"
    case red = "#FF6978"
    case green = "#BCE784"
    case blue = "#B1DDF1"
    case yellow = "#FFFD98"
    case purple = "#A09ABC"

    private var uiColor : UIColor {
        return UIColor(hex: self)
    }
    private var all: [UIColor] {
        return [MyColors.background, .stroke, .red,… etc ]
    }

    var randomColor: UIColor {
        let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(all.count)))
        return all[index].uiColor
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I went with the first answer, but thank you for the effort :)

Comment: I deleted my answer because I overlooked the *random* part.

Comment: "Enums may not contain stored properties"

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to make the enum CaseIterable so that .allCases array becomes available

```
enum MyColors : String, CaseIterable {
    case background = "#373737"
    case stroke = "#FFFCF9"
    case red = "#FF6978"
    case green = "#BCE784"
    case blue = "#B1DDF1"
    case yellow = "#FFFD98"
    case purple = "#A09ABC"

    private var uiColor : UIColor {
        return UIColor(hex: self)
    }

    static func randomColor() -> UIColor {
        return MyColors.allCases[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(MyColors.allCases.count)))].uiColor
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your enum implements `CaseIterable`, you can use `allCases()` as Richard already described.
In addition to that, you can use `randomElement()` to get a randomised value:

```
   MyColors.allcases.randomElement()
```